# initializing string in class using constructor

Tags: visual-c++

I am creating a class that has two members string and int 
I want to use the constructor to initialize both of these two members to use them.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class donation_1
{
public:
    //string name;
    const char* name;
    int donation_amount;
    const static size_t string_size = sizeof(string);
    const static size_t int_size = sizeof(int);

    donation_1(char* name_1 = "Noname", int amount = 0) : name(name_1), donation_amount(amount) {};
};




int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("donation_total1.txt", ios_base::app);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        donation_1("xxxx", 20).writedata(file);
        donation_1("yyyy", 30).writedata(file);
        donation_1("zzzz", 40).writedata(file);
        donation_1("MMMM", 50).writedata(file);
        donation_1("BBBB", 60).writedata(file);
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file couldn't be opened" << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I want to use the constructor to initialize the class variables which I will be using to update a file, however, what I am getting is this error. this error is regarding initializing the string class member.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0310   default argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *" Stream_File_Lab D:\INVSPRIVATE\C++\Projects\Stream_File_Lab\donation_1.h    17

Answer (score 1):

The error message is makes it pretty clear. The variable 'name' is declared as const char* but the value being assigned to it is only char*  i.e. the const-ness is missing, hence the type incompatibility error throws up.
Please, google for pointer to a const value and how to use them.
Maybe check [this tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/610-pointers-and-const/)